# How to remove script content in innerHtml in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to remove contents inside script tag when i look into the console for result.

now it is showing  informations along with correct results.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 
 
 var texta=document.documentElement.innerHTML;
 
 
 var result = texta.match(/(.*)[:](.*)/g);
 var rex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
 var htmltag=[];
 //console.log(result)
 for (index = 0; index < result.length; ++index) {
      //console.log(index)
      htmltag[index]=strip_html_tags(result[index]);
      console.log(htmltag[index]. split(/[\<>&=:]/));
 
 } 


 function strip_html_tags(str)
 {
    if ((str===null) || (str===''))
        return false;
   else
    str = str.toString();
   return str.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
 }
 
</script>
```

```html
<html><li>Product Code : Product 15</li>
<li>Product Points : 100</li>
<span>Product : In Stock</span>
</html>
```

In console i am getting

1. ["Product Code ", " Product 15"]
2. ["Product Points ", " 100"]
3. ["Product", "In Stock"]
4. [" var result ", " texta.match(/(.*)", "/g);"]
5. [" console.log(htmltag[index]. split(/[\", "", "", "]/));"]

i do not want  4th and 5th as it is come from inside javascript.

Comment: Do you want to remove any script tag or just this one ?

Comment: any javascript script tags

Comment: can you be very specific what content do you want to remove?(keeping above output in mind)

Comment: @HameedSyed please check now.

Comment: You just want to have the content of your li tags into an array ? if so, try yo use document.getElementsByTagName('li')

Comment: anything that matches regular expression not just li tag

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Your now parsing the whole html code, anything in javascript tags can be used in javascript, there is no need to parse it. As I see, you just want to be able to access any other tags content and apply a regex on it. Am I wrong ? If I am you just have to exclude script tags in your regex, but it's easier to use native function to access the current dom.

Comment: @vijaikarthik,you need only the content of li's if I am not wrong.As suggested by disfigure you need to use other than regular expression.Parsing whole textArea with regular expression is cumbersome.

Comment: purpose is getting all possible product specification in any ecommerce product detail page.most product details page will have atleast one colon seperated product specifications.so i am using script so.

Comment: You can remove all scripts from "innerHTML" [like so](https://jsfiddle.net/vzyo202e/1/).

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of issues with your code.

See my [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ryanbriscall/4w5t09fm/), where I've adjusted your code a bit.

**JS**

```
<script>
  var texta=document.getElementsByClassName('details');

  for(var i=0; i <= texta.length; i++) {

  var result = texta[i].innerHTML.match(/(.*)[:](.*)/g);
  var rex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
  var htmltag=[];

  for (index = 0; index < result.length; ++index) {
     htmltag[index]=strip_html_tags(result[index]);
     console.log(htmltag[index]. split(/[\<>&=:]/));
  } 
}
function strip_html_tags(str)
{
    if ((str===null) || (str===''))
        return false;
    else
        str = str.toString();
    return str.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
}

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<ul class="details">
<li>Product Code : Product 15</li>
<li>Product Points : 100</li>
<li>Product = In Stock</li>
</ul>
<div class="details">
   <div>Product Code : Product 15</div>
   <div>Product Points : 100</div>
   <div>Product = In Stock</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**Output**

```
(2) ["Product Code ", " Product 15"]
(2) ["Product Points ", " 100"]
```

Your now able to add a css class called "details" and all the content of each "details" dom content and apply a regex match.

Comment: Hi dude, cool share for him but its what is looking for : "anything that matches regular expression not just li tag" I edited your post

Comment: thanks but not just li tag.It may come from span tag too.

Comment: Corrected, the JavaScript in the post works perfectly, waiting for OP to accept my edition.

Answer (score 0):

It is working.Thanks everyone.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 
 var texta=document.documentElement.innerHTML;

 function strip_html_tags(str)
 {
    if ((str===null) || (str===''))
        return false;
   else
    str = str.toString();
   return str.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
 }

 var sratscript = texta.indexOf("script")-1;
 var endscript = texta.lastIndexOf("script")+1;
 var arr = texta.split('');
 var removed = arr.splice(sratscript,endscript," "); // THistr 
 texta = arr.join('');
 //console.log(texta )
 var result = texta.match(/(.*)[:](.*)/g);
 var rex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
 var htmltag=[];
 for (index = 0; index < result.length; ++index) {
      //console.log(index)
      htmltag[index]=strip_html_tags(result[index]);
     
  console.log(htmltag[index]. split(/[\<>&=:]/))
 } 

</script>
```

```html
<html><li>Product Code : Product 15</li>
<li>Product Points : 100</li>
<span>Product : In Stock</span>
</html>
```